# What is the purpose of using shift in shell scripts?

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I have came across this script:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                           

if (( $# < 3 )); then
  echo "$0 old_string new_string file [file...]"
  exit 0
else
  ostr="$1"; shift
  nstr="$1"; shift  
fi

echo "Replacing \"$ostr\" with \"$nstr\""
for file in $@; do
  if [ -f $file ]; then
    echo "Working with: $file"
    eval "sed 's/"$ostr"/"$nstr"/g' $file" > $file.tmp 
    mv $file.tmp $file
  fi  
done
```

What is the meaning of the lines where they use `shift`? I presume the script should be used with at least arguments so...?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`shift` is a `bash` built-in which kind of removes arguments from the beginning of the argument list. Given that the 3 arguments provided to the script are available in `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, then a call to `shift`  will make `$2` the new `$1`.
A `shift 2` will shift by two making new `$1` the old `$3`.
For more information, see here:

- http://ss64.com/bash/shift.html
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html

Comment: +1 Note it's not *rotating* them, it's *shifting* them off the array (of arguments).  Shift/unshift and pop/push are common names for this general kind of manipulation (see, e.g., bash's `pushd` and `popd`).

Comment: The definitive reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shift

Comment: @goldilocks very true. Instead of "rotate" I should have better found a way to use another word, something like "move the arguments forward in the argument variables". Anyway I hope the examples in the text and the link to the reference will have made it clear nonetheless.

Comment: Though the script mentions `bash`, the question is general to all shells, therefore the Posix standard prevails: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set

Answer (score 57):

As goldilocks’ comment and humanity’s references describe,
`shift` reassigns the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.)
so that `$1` takes on the old value of `$2`,
`$2` takes on the value of `$3`, etc.<sup>*</sup> 
The old value of `$1` is discarded.  (`$0` is not changed.) 
Some reasons for doing this include:

- It lets you access the tenth argument (if there is one) more easily. 
  `$10` doesn’t work – it’s interpreted as `$1` concatenated with a `0`
  (and so might produce something like `Hello0`). 
  After a `shift`, the tenth argument becomes `$9`. 
  (However, in most modern shells, you can use `${10}`.)
- As the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) demonstrates,
  it can be used to loop through the arguments. 
  IMNSHO, this is clumsy; `for` is much better for that.
- As in your example script,
  it makes it easy to process all of the arguments the same way except for a few. 
  For example, in your script,
  `$1` and `$2` are text strings,
  while `$3` and all other parameters are file names.

So here’s how it plays out. 
Suppose your script is called `Patryk_script` and it is called as

```
Patryk_script USSR Russia Treaty1 Atlas2 Pravda3
```

The script sees

```
$1 = USSR
$2 = Russia
$3 = Treaty1
$4 = Atlas2
$5 = Pravda3
```

The statement `ostr="$1"` sets variable `ostr` to `USSR`. 
The first `shift` statement changes the positional parameters as follows:

```
$1 = Russia
$2 = Treaty1
$3 = Atlas2
$4 = Pravda3
```

The statement `nstr="$1"` sets variable `nstr` to `Russia`. 
The second `shift` statement changes the positional parameters as follows:

```
$1 = Treaty1
$2 = Atlas2
$3 = Pravda3
```

And then the `for` loop changes `USSR` (`$ostr`) to `Russia` (`$nstr`)
in the files `Treaty1`, `Atlas2`, and `Pravda3`.

---

---

There are a few problems with the script.

1. ```
   for file in $@; do
   ```

   If the script is invoked as

   ```
   Patryk_script USSR Russia Treaty1 "World Atlas2" Pravda3
   ```

   it sees

   ```
   $1 = USSR
   $2 = Russia
   $3 = Treaty1
   $4 = World Atlas2
   $5 = Pravda3
   ```

   but, because `$@` isn’t quoted, the space in `World Atlas2` isn’t quoted,
   and the `for` loop thinks it has four files: `Treaty1`, `World`, `Atlas2`,
   and `Pravda3`. 
   This should be either

   ```
   for file in "$@"; do
   ```

   (to quote any special characters in the arguments) or simply

   ```
   for file do
   ```

   (which is equivalent to the longer version).
2. ```
   eval "sed 's/"$ostr"/"$nstr"/g' $file"
   ```

   There’s no need for this to be an `eval`,
   and passing unchecked user input to an `eval` can be dangerous. 
   For example, if the script is invoked as

   ```
   Patryk_script "'; rm *;'" Russia Treaty1 Atlas2 Pravda3
   ```

   it will execute `rm *`! 
   This is a big concern if the script can be run
   with privileges higher than those of the user who invokes it;
   e.g., if it can be run via `sudo` or invoked from a web interface. 
   It’s probably not so important if you just use it as yourself,
   in your directory. 
   But it can be changed to

   ```
   sed "s/$ostr/$nstr/g" "$file"
   ```

   This still has some risks, but they are much less severe.
3. `if [ -f $file ]`, `> $file.tmp` and `mv $file.tmp $file`
   should be `if [ -f "$file" ]`, `> "$file.tmp"` and `mv "$file.tmp" "$file"`,
   respectively, to handle file names
   that might have spaces (or other funny characters) in them. 
   (The `eval "sed …` command also mangles file names that have spaces in them.)

---

<sup>*</sup> `shift` takes an optional argument:
a positive integer that specifies how many parameters to shift. 
The default is one (`1`). 
For example, `shift 4` causes `$5`
to become `$1`,
`$6` to become `$2`, and so on. 
(Note that the example in the [Bash Guide for Beginners](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) is wrong.) 
And so your script could be modified to say

```
ostr="$1"
nstr="$2"
shift 2
```

which might be considered to be more clear.

---

---

**End Note** / Warning:

The Windows Command Prompt (batch file) language
also supports a `SHIFT` command,
which does basically the same thing as the `shift` command in Unix shells,
with one striking difference,
which I’ll hide to try to prevent people from being confused by it:

> - A command like `SHIFT 4` is an error,
>   yielding an “Invalid parameter to SHIFT command” error message.
>
>   `SHIFT /n`, where *`n`* is an integer between 0 and 8,
>   is valid — but it doesn’t shift *`n`* *times*. 
>   It shifts once, *starting with* the *n* th argument. 
>   So `SHIFT /4`  causes `%5` (the fifth argument) to become `%4,` 
>   `%6` to become `%5`, and so on, leaving arguments 0 through 3 alone.

Comment: `shift` can be applied to `while`, `until`, and even `for` loops for handling arrays in much more subtle ways than can a simple `for` loop. I often find it useful  in `for` loops like...  `set -f -- $args; IFS=$split; for arg do set -- $arg; shift "${number_of_fields_to_discard}" && fn_that_wants_split_arg "$arg"; done`

Answer (score 5):

The simplest explanation is this. Consider the command:

```
/bin/command.sh SET location Cebu
/bin/command.sh SET location Cebu, Philippines 6014
```

Without the help of `shift` you cannot extract the complete value of the location because this value could get arbitrarily long. When you shift two times, the args `SET` and `location` are removed such that:

```
x="$@"
echo "location = $x"
```

Take a very long stare at the `$@` thing. That means, it can save the complete location into variable `x` despite the spaces and comma that it has. So in summary, we call `shift` and then later we retrieve the value of what is left from the variable `$@`.

**UPDATE**
I am adding below a very short snippet showing the concept and usefulness of `shift` without which, it would be very,very difficult to extract the fields correctly.

```
#!/bin/sh
#

[ $# -eq 0 ] && return 0

a=$1
shift
b=$@
echo $a
[ -n "$b" ] && echo $b
```

**Explanation**: After the `shift`, the variable **b** shall contain the rest of the stuff being passed in, no matter of spaces or etc. The `[ -n "$b" ] && echo $b` is a protection such that we only print **b** if it has a content.

Comment: (1) This is not the simplest explanation.  It’s ***an*** interesting angle.  (2) But as long as you want to concatenate a bunch of arguments (or all of them), you might want to get into the habit of using `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.  (3) I was going to upvote your answer, but I didn’t, because you say “shift two times” but you don’t actually show it in code.  (4) If you want a script to be able to take a multi-word value from the command line, it’s probably better to require the user to put the entire value into quotes. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  You might not care today, but your approach doesn’t allow you to have multiple spaces (``Philippines   6014``), leading spaces, trailing spaces, or tabs.  (5) BTW, you may also be able to do what you’re doing here in bash with `x="${*:3}"`.

Comment: I tried to decipher where your '*** doesn't allow multiple spaces ***' comment is coming from because this is not related to the `shift` command. You maybe referring to $@ versus $\* subtle differences. But the fact still remains, that my snippet above can accurately extract the location no matter how many spaces it has either trailing or in the front it doesn't matter. After the shift, location will contain the correct location.

Answer (score 4):

`shift` treat command line arguments as a FIFO queue, 
it popleft element every time it's invoked.

```
array = [a, b, c]
shift equivalent to
array.popleft
[b, c]
$1, $2,$3 can be interpreted as index of the array.
$# is the length of array
```