# Stop and Start Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have created a simple script to start a process, but I am not sure how to add a stop step since the process is ran/stopped manually

Currently, to start the process, we use a single command line

```
omrun dssdaemon <a string to run>
```

Then, to stop it, the usual ps command

```
ps -ef | grep -i dssdaemon

kill -9 <PID>
```

I have gotten this far

```
#!/bin/sh
# Priti's script to start dss daemon
pid=$(ps -ef | grep dssdaemon | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
DSS_START=omrun dssdaemon <a string to run>

$DSS_START; sleep 15;
echo "DSS Daemons is running with PID[S] below" && $pid
```

The process has some limitation with using pidof, that is why I have created the awk string instead.

I could really use some help with adding a status and kill step.

Something like this

```
# status dss daemon
DSS Daemon is running with PID[S] below
123456
432145

# start dss daemon
DSS Daemon is started with PID[S] below
123456
432145

# stop dss daemon
DSS Daemon with PID[S] below were killed
123456
432145
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `killall` or `pkill` tools. They do send a signal to the process just as `kill` does. But instead of pid, they look for the process by its name. And if you have several demons running - all of them would got the signal.

```
killall -9 dssdaemon
```

Comment: And may be try withouth the `-9` to let the process terminate in an orderly fashion.  The default SIGTERM should do the trick.  Use SIGKILL (-9) as a last resort only.

Comment: Thank you for that, I have added it into the script. But I am not sure how to create a status/stop/start like that of systemctl to make this work in a single script.

Comment: @PritiPatel You could try checking what arguments the script was invoked with [using `$#` and `shift`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174566/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shift-in-shell-scripts)